# FreeWITCH: Show Codecs not showing H264 codec?

Tags: pjsip, freeswitch

I am trying to make a video call using FreeSWITCH and pjsip library. Audio calls working without any issues. To enable video I made following changes:

```
1. I followed all the steps mentioned here.
PJSIP video user guide (https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Video_Users_Guide)


2. FreeSWITCH                
a. Updated /usr/local/freeswitch/conf/vars.xml with h264 codec.
   <XPREPROCESScmd="set"data="global_codec_prefs=H264,OPUS,G722,PCMU,PCMA"/>
```

```
b. However, h264 is not showing in the codecs list (show codecs)            

c. when I make a video, call... FreeSWITCH is converting it to an audio call. When I initiate a call Video port was opened but later it was closed.
```

From pjsip to FreeSwitch(1st leg) it was video call... but 2nd leg is audo call.

v=0

o=FreeSWITCH 1540768194 1540768195 IN IP4 192.168.100.41

s=FreeSWITCH

c=IN IP4 192.168.100.41

t=0 0

m=audio 26506 RTP/AVP 0 96

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:96 0-16

a=ptime:20

a=rtcp:26507 IN IP4 192.168.100.41

m=video 0 RTP/AVP 19

Please let me know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below command in fs_cli whether it returns true or false.

`module_exists mod_h26x`

If it returns true then h264 codec is loaded else not loaded. for loading the 
module perform below command

`load mod_h26x`

If you see any error while loading module then you need to compile the mod_h26x from freeswitch source.This module will present in the mod/codec directory. just do make and make install in module source code directory, and load the module by above command.

Comment: 1. "module_exists mod_h26x" returned "false". 2. Then I ran "load mod_h26x" command... h264 codec loaded. 3. Now it is showing in the "show codecs" list as well. Thank You.